# Finding phishing sites to certain domain

Tags: phishing, kali-linux, dns-domain, domain

My work currently involve finding phishing site to a certain domain/ company. I was wondering if there are some tools/ Online services that I can use to find phishing sites. I would like to know;

> **Searching for registered domains based on keyword?**

There are tons of online service which will allow you to search for domains that are `unregistered` or `available for sale` but none I could find which would allow me search for only `registered` ones. What I am looking for here is all the registered domain that are based on my keyword.

> **Finding phishing sites based on deceptive domains?**

I use bit of bitsquatting/ Addition/ Deletion/ Omission to look for registered domain that are deceptive to the domain in question. I am looking for an automated tool which can apply some other techniques if there are. For e.g. If I am looking for phishing domains of company.com I am hardly likely to arrive at comapanypvtltd.com ..etc.

> **Finding phishing sites based on Keywords?**

Searching based on keywords is hard and produces a lot of noise. I would consider the company name, keywords from their respective industry. For e.g. digibucks.com a made-up online digital currency company, I am definitely going to look for digibuckswallet.com and other gTLD & ccTLD of same.
I am looking for a tool or online service which offers similar functionality.
FYI dnslytics.com has the similar feature to search for domains based on keywords. Sometimes its result are very good.

> **Finding phishing site based on similar look and feel?**

I am particularly interested in this as I have not been able to find any good resource on this. I was wondering if It would be possible to search for websites that look exactly the same as website in question. It is possible search based on HTML/CSS of the page or any other techniques around it.

Any additional techniques/ resource would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: See also [Find Phishing Sites in Certificate Transparency Logs](https://duo.com/decipher/find-phishing-sites-in-certificate-transparency-logs)